# pushing an object onto an array from an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching property and value pairs (second argument). Each property and value pair of the source object has to be present in the object from the collection if it is to be included in the returned array.

For example, if the first argument is

```js
[{
  first: "Romeo",
  last: "Montague"
}, {
  first: "Mercutio",
  last: null
}, {
  first: "Tybalt",
  last: "Capulet"
}]
```

, and the second argument is `{ last: "Capulet" }`, then you must return the third object from the array (the first argument), because it contains the property and it's value, that was passed on as the second argument.

So far this is what I've tried but I either get nothing in my new array or all the objects pushed in:

```
function where(collection, source) {
    var arr = [];
    // iterating through the properties in course
    for (var name in source){
        // if the name from source is found in collection
        for (var i =0; i<collection.length; i++) {
            if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(name))
            {
            // push the object onto the array?????
                arr.push(collection[i]);
                console.log(collection[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

where([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null   }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

Comment: You can loop over array using `Array.prototype.forEach`, or you can use `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

If I understood correctly, you want something like this;

```
var src = {last: "Capulet"};

var arr = [
{
  first: "Romeo",
  last: "Montague"
},
{
  first: "Mercutio",
  last: null
},
{
  first: "Tybalt",
  last: "Capulet"
}];

var newArr = arr.filter(function(item) {
    if(Object.keys(src).every(function(k){ 
            return src.hasOwnProperty(k) && item.hasOwnProperty(k) && src[k] === item[k]}))
  {
    return item;
  }
});

console.log(newArr);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qjzp3vdo/)

Answer (score 1):

i have two possible solutions

1. you could use native function filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter
2. or use a library such as lodash with the "_.filter" function: https://lodash.com/docs

exemples:

- using lodash function:

`var result = _.filter(array, {last: "Capulet"});`

```js
var arr = [
{
  first: "Romeo",
  last: "Montague"
},
{
  first: "Mercutio",
  last: null
},
{
  first: "Tybalt",
  last: "Capulet"
}];
 

 
var res = _.filter(arr, {last: "Capulet"});
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.1.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wanting to write a function from scratch to meet your requirement, then UnderscoreJS might be at your rescue. Checkout the link below.

[_.where(list, properties) in underscorejs library](http://underscorejs.org/#where)

```
var list = [{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null   }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }];

console.log(_.where(list, { last: "Capulet" })); // prints on console
// [{  first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet"  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
function where(collection, source) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
        var found = true;
        for (var name in source){
            //If one of the property does not match, do not return the object
            if (collection[i][name] != source[name]){ found = false; }
        }
        if (found) {
            //If you want the object
            return collection[i];

            //If you want the object in an array
            return [collection[i]];
        }
    }
}
```